# How to add and configure asmack in android

Tags: asmack

Please can you help with a break down of how you got asmack working in your android. I cant get it to work for my application. I keep geting java.lang.verifyError.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in aSmack's README?

Answer (score 3):

Be sure to include latest version i.e. [asmack-android-17-0.8.3](http://asmack.freakempire.de/0.8.3/asmack-android-17-0.8.3.jar) of asmack library in libs folder.
Adding this might remove `java.lang.VerifyError`.

I do it the following way, it works perfectly.

```
public void login(View view)
{
     new Connection().execute("username", "password");
}

private class Connection extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer>
{
    private static final int CONNECTION_FAILURE = 0;
    private static final int LOGIN_FAILURE = 1;
    private static final int SUCCESS = 2;

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... strings)
    {
        ConnectionConfiguration conConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration("192.168.1.100", 5222, "domain");
        connection = new XMPPConnection(conConfig);
  try
  {
      connection.connect();
      Log.i("AppName", "CONNECTED TO " + connection.getHost());
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
      Log.e("AppName", e.getMessage());
      return CONNECTION_FAILURE;
  }
  try
  {
      connection.login(strings[0], strings[1]);
      Log.i("AppName", "LOGGED IN AS " + connection.getUser());
      Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
      connection.sendPacket(presence);
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
      Log.e("AppName", e.getMessage());
      return LOGIN_FAILURE;
  }
  return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1907588 did you try using the latest version of asmack library.

Comment: I had to go through a long process to figure out the third parameter. It wasn't documented here: https://github.com/Flowdalic/asmack/blob/master/static-src/custom/org/jivesoftware/smack/AndroidConnectionConfiguration.java